# export sql agent job result to .csv file

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

As a perfomance optimization, I did index rebuild on database.

I used ALTER TABLE ALL ON @table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = @fillfactor).

I would like to schedule this as a agent job.

Now my requirement as:

1. I need to export the index stats to csv file before rebuilding index
2. rebuild the index
3. stats of index export to csv file after rebuilding index.

I palced the rebuild index script in agent job and I did manually executed the index stats query to see the status before and after agent job.

how do I need to automate the process of

1. Index stats before rebuilding
2. rebuilding
3. stats after rebuiling.

I am using this script for stats.

`DECLARE @DATABASE VARCHAR(10)= 'AdventureWorksDW2008'
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(IPS.OBJECT_ID) AS [TABLENAME],
   SI.NAME AS [INDEXNAME],
   IPS.INDEX_TYPE_DESC,
   IPS.AVG_FRAGMENTATION_IN_PERCENT, 
   IPS.AVG_FRAGMENT_SIZE_IN_PAGES, 
   IPS.AVG_PAGE_SPACE_USED_IN_PERCENT,
   IPS.RECORD_COUNT, 
   IPS.GHOST_RECORD_COUNT,
   IPS.FRAGMENT_COUNT,
   IPS.AVG_FRAGMENT_SIZE_IN_PAGES
FROM SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_PHYSICAL_STATS(DB_ID(N''+ @DATABASE +''), NULL, NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED') IPS
   JOIN SYS.TABLES ST WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = ST.OBJECT_ID
   JOIN SYS.INDEXES SI WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = SI.OBJECT_ID AND IPS.INDEX_ID = SI.INDEX_ID
WHERE ST.IS_MS_SHIPPED = 0
ORDER BY 1,5`

and for rebuilding.

```
ALTER TABLE ALL ON @table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = @fillfactor).
```

thanks
prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if you put your script sql into a proc called sp_IndexStats you could then write a second proc that looks something like:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'osql.exe -S YourServerName -U sa -P yourpassword -Q "EXEC     sp_IndexStats" -o "C:\mypath\IndexBefore.csv"'
GO
ALTER TABLE ALL ON @table REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = @fillfactor)
GO
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'osql.exe -S YourServerName -U sa -P yourpassword -Q "EXEC sp_IndexStats" -o "C:\mypath\IndexAfter.csv"'
```

Comment: Thank you, I created one SSIS package in an alterantive way and it has solved the issue but your solution is lot simpler than what I implemented however there is no performance issue in the approach but your approach inspired me. thanks